# How to send ethernet packet to the fpga board?

Tags: ethernet

I have fpga board and MAC layer implemented on and i want to send data to the board using ethernet. Can any one help me how do it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something that implements tcp/ip stack or other stack. It could be some software core. Check on opencores.